# CSV File downloads from Node Express server

Tags: node.js, express, json2csv

I have an API backend with Node and Express. I am trying to take some filtered data from the frontend and create a CSV file and download it for the user. I have been using [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv). I am able to create the data file correctly and when I use that file in my express route I download a file that just says undefined. At first, I thought it was an asynchronous issue, but after using a setTimeout as a test to see if that was an issue I still get the undefined data file. Console logging the "csvData" shows the correct data.

Express route to download the file.

```
app.post('/api/downloads/filtered', (req, res) => {
    let fields = [];
    fields = Object.keys(req.body[0])
    const filteredData = req.body;
    const json2csvParser = new json2csv({fields: fields});
    const csvData = json2csvParser.parse(filteredData);
    console.log(csvData)
    fs.writeFile('./report.csv', csvData, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('created report.csv');
            res.download('./report.csv');
        }
    })
})
```

I'm using Vue on the frontend, I get the file when clicking a button not sure if that is something I should include.

Comment: Can you see the data in the file "report.csv"?

Comment: Yes, that is what is so weird. If ssh'd into the server I can see the file has the correct data. When downloaded to the browser it just says undefined. in one of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring out my issue. I found that downloading in a post request didn't seem to be possible. I needed a get request. Since the data for the file came in the request body I ended up keeping the post request to create the file and creating a separate get request to download the file this seemed to work fine but didn't find it documented anywhere so I wasn't sure if a better way exists.

```
app.post('/api/downloads/filtered', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    let fields = [];
    fields = Object.keys(req.body[0])
    const filteredData = req.body;

    const json2csvParser = new json2csv({fields: fields});
    const csvData = json2csvParser.parse(filteredData);
    console.log(csvData)
    fs.writeFile('./report.csv', csvData, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('created report.csv');
        }
    })
})

app.get('/api/downloads/filtered', (req, res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {res.download('./report.csv')}, 1000)
})
```